# Geometric optics- lenses

Tags: reflection, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

I was wondering why would light rays converge at a biconvex lens and diverge at a biconcave lens? Is it concerning on how light rays behave in a convex or a concave mirror?

Also, is it possible to predict or sketch how would light rays behave using the angle of incidence and angle of refraction?

Comment: Try googling by the phrase "lens as composed of prisms", and u might get a good reason.

Comment: I suspect you meant biconvex and biconcave. If you truly did mean "bio" rather than "bi" as a prefix, this question is perhaps better suited for the biology SE site.

Comment: Sorry. It was indeed "bi" sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think,

At P1, By Snells law, Since the glass is a denser medium(as compared to air), the velocity of light is less than that in air. Therefore, the light ray deflects towards the normal.[image]

Afterwards, at P2, Since the air is a rarer medium than glass, By Snell's Law,
light gets deflected away from the normal.[image]

In the same way you can explain that of a biconcave lens.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How did you know how the normal lines are oriented at each point? I actually thought about your answer but I couldn't figure out how to orient the normal lines at each point.

Comment: The surfaces of most lenses are sections of [spheres](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenmak.html). It's possible to prove that you get better focusing if the surfaces are instead [paraboloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid).

Comment: The normals are always taken perpendicular to the surface( at that point) .

Answer (score -1):

You can show it using Snell's law of refraction, or the least time principle. However, this is not similar to convex or concave mirrors.